# use string out of a mongodb function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

need some help with node js and mongodb
how can I return the resp? cause now it returns "undefined";

```
function(table, where, to_select) {
  var r = {};
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db", function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
      collection = db.collection(table);
      collection.find(where, to_select).toArray(function(err, resp) {
        r.t = resp; // return THIS
      });
    }
  });
  return r.t; //returns undefined //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use callback because DB query in asynchronous operation. So your return gets called before find actually return results. Here is the fix

`function runQuery(table,where,to_select, callback){
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db", function(err, db) {
        if (err) {return callback(err);}
        collection = db.collection(table);
        collection.find(where,to_select).toArray(function(err, resp) {
            callback(err, resp);
        });
  }); 
}`

And to call function you need

```
runQuery(table, where, select, function(err, results){
   ///do something with results.
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting "call back is not a function"

Comment: You sure that you run as we told you.. Callback it's just a name of callback function. All should work if you copy code directly. Look at runQuery example

Comment: I even simplify a little bit more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122025/discussion-between-mykola-borysyuk-and-).

Answer (score 1):

`MongoClient.connect` &  `collection.find` are `asynchronous` functions.
To get value of `resp` properly you can make `getData` function `asynchronous` as below.

```
function getData(table, where, to_select, callback) { // We pass callback function 
    var r = {};
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db", function(err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            collection = db.collection(table);
            collection.find(where, to_select).toArray(function(err, resp) {
             // r.t = resp; no need to assign as you want resp only
             callback(err,resp); // return resp
            })
        }else
           callback(err);// return with error 
    });
    //return r.t; r.t will be undefined as r.t is not updated yet, so we can remove this
}


/*Now you can call as below
  getData(whatever,)whatever,whatever,function(err,resp){
      console.log(resp);// You will get result here
  })*/
```